# Could not find stylesheet file 'css/style.css' linked from the template. Got this error while interfacing bootstrap with Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular2-bootstrapping

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

this is what the part of the code that throughs me the error just like for css I get error for all the plugins like bootstrap, owl-carousel, magnific-popup

Comment: You would need to show your project structure for anyone to help. Basically, we don't put the stylesheets directly in the index.html file, but reference it in the `anguar.json` file. Check this : https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config

Comment: In my case this needs to be a link, I see the OP question is a little different. The reason is if the CSS needs to change I need the mobile app to pick it up from the server so that I don't have to build a new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can move all the CSS files to src/assets/css/ and then add these codes in angular.json

```
"styles": [
      "src/assets/css/style.css",
      "src/assets/css/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css",
      "src/assets/css/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css",
    ]
```

That could fix the problem. 
 Another solution could help:
In your file ***login.component.ts*** add

```
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css', './Your-Path/Your-File.css']
```